# JodaTime DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, formatting, jodatime

I have this sql query and Java code:

```
    select to_char(start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS start_date FROM table

    LogServiceFactory.getInstance().logError("-------From the Db " + rs.getString("start_date"));

    LogServiceFactory.getInstance().logError("-------Formatter " + DateTime.parse(rs.getString("start_date"), formatter));

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/YYYY");

    object.setStart_date(DateTime.parse(rs.getString("start_date"), formatter));
```

Here's what's in my log file:

2012-08-16 17:48:26 - -------From the Db 08/08/2012

2012-08-16 17:48:26 - -------Formatter 2012-08-08T00:00:00.000-04:00

Why is it that the formatter is converting 08/08/2012 to 2012-08-08T00:00:00.000-04:00

My assumption was that the date would come back as 08/08/2012.

Am I not using the formatter correctly?

Comment: Just a stylistic thing but I would name the setter `object.setStartDate(..)` not `setStart_date(..)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that `DateTime.parse` returns a new [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object. So you call the standard `toString()` method, which returns a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted date pattern.

You can use `.toString("dd/MM/yyyy")` for your log message.

Comment: If you use this pattern often, you can use .toString(formatter).